# Error while deploying web application in weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to deploy a web application in weblogic application server 10.3

After deploying when i try to activate the changes i am receiving the following exception

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:965)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:958)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:37)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processServlets(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:228)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:211)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1287)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:412)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:456)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:910)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:364)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:180)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:388)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:616)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:16)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:155)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:198)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:89)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:725)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1190)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:248)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:157)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:965)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:958)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:37)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processServlets(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:228)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:211)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1287)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:412)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:456)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:910)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:364)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:180)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:388)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:616)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:16)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:155)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:198)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:89)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:725)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1190)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:248)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:157)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

I understand that the jar file containing the following class **org/apache/commons/digester/Digester** is missing in the server runtime.

I added this jar in $DOMAIN/lib and restarted the weblogic server. After deploying i receiving the same error.

Please advise.

Comment: Try to add the jar in your startWeblogic.cmd script by setting the classpath

Answer (score 0):

It is a NoClassDefFound Error and not a ClassNotFoundException.
Check if you do not have a conflit with another version of the same library, and check also dependencies. Maybe, this library requires other jars to be added to the classpath.